# Formal verification and verification jobs

Tags: verification

Im an EE student (second year), and I wanted to ask about verificarion jobs.

Does "Formal verification" is the same as just "verification" ? Could not find the diiference

Comment: Formal verification engineers are more formal, you're required to wear a suit! OK, joking aside: 1) Why are you even worrying about this? Look at the **skills** that are required for a job, not what it is called. 2) Different companies have different names for the same job. 3) As a 2nd year student, worry about **skills** that interest **you** and at which **you** can become good at. Then **for sure** you will find a job that you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formal verification is not the same as "verification" although in a job posting there may be some sloppy language used and it might not be clear.

The term "formal verification" is the process of proving that a particular design meets the design requirements.  It uses tools and processes that are intended to comprehensively expose any shortcomings in the implementation.

This is most commonly found in defense, aerospace, medical, and similar industries where an improperly implemented design might cause significant impact.  In other words it's one thing if your iPhone malfunctions, it's something else entirely if your nuclear-tipped ballistic missile guidance computer fails to perform as required.

Formal verification is finding its way into more and more processes however as in many cases the costs of a redesign both in terms of absolute money and lost opportunity in the market make mistakes in implementation ever more costly.

You might read through this article:

To quote the opening paragraph:

> Formal verification is the process of checking whether a design
> satisfies some requirements (properties). We are concerned with the
> formal verification of designs that may be specified hierarchically
> (as illustrated in the previous section); this is also consistent with
> how a human designer operates. In order to formally verify a design,
> it must first be converted into a simpler ``verifiable'' format. The
> design is specified as a set of interacting systems; each has a finite
> number of configurations, called states. States and transition between
> states constitute FSMs. The entire system is an FSM, which can be
> obtained by composing the FSMs associated with each component. Hence
> the first step in verification consists of obtaining a complete FSM
> description of the system. Given a present state (or current
> configuration), the next state (or successive configuration) of an FSM
> can be written as a function of its present state and inputs
> (transition function or transition relation).

[Formal Verification](https://ptolemy.berkeley.edu/projects/embedded/research/vis/doc/VisUser/vis_user/node4.html)